# Which API Group in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

How do I determine which  `apiGroup` any given resource belongs in?

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: thing
rules:
- apiGroups: ["<wtf goes here>"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
  resourceNames: []
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To get API resources - supported by your Kubernetes cluster:

```
 kubectl api-resources -o wide

example:
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIGROUP                       NAMESPACED   KIND                             VERBS
deployments                       deploy       apps                           true         Deployment                   [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
deployments                       deploy       extensions                     true         Deployment                   [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
```

To get API versions -  supported by your Kubernetes cluster:

```
kubectl api-versions
```

You can verify f.e. deployment:

```
kubectl explain deploy 

KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  extensions/v1beta1

DESCRIPTION:
     DEPRECATED - This group version of Deployment is deprecated by
     apps/v1beta2/Deployment.
```

Furthermore you can investigate with api-version:

```
kubectl explain deploy --api-version apps/v1
```

Shortly you an specify in you apiGroups like:

```
apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps"]
```

You can also configure those settings for your cluster using (for example to test it will work with next [1.16 release](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/#enabling-api-groups)) by passing options into `--runtime-config`  in [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/#kube-apiserver).

Additional resources:

- [api Resources](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-api-resources-which-group-and-version-to-use/):
- [Kubernetes Deprecation Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-policy/#deprecating-parts-of-the-api)
- Additional Notable Feature Updates [for specific release please follow](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#kubernetes-v115-release-notes)  like:

  `Continued deprecation of extensions/v1beta1, apps/v1beta1, and apps/v1beta2 APIs; these extensions will be retired in 1.16!`

Comment: This shown API version now, not group

Answer (score 11):

`kubectl api-resources -o wide` provide  the supported API resources on the system.

```
[suresh.vishnoi@xxx1309 ~]$ kubectl api-resources -o wide
NAME                                  SHORTNAMES      APIGROUP                       NAMESPACED   KIND                                 VERBS
bindings                                                                             true         Binding                              [create]
componentstatuses                     cs                                             false        ComponentStatus                      [get list]
configmaps                            cm                                             true         ConfigMap                            [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
endpoints                             ep                                             true         Endpoints                            [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
events                                ev                                             true         Event                                [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
controllerrevisions                                   apps                           true         ControllerRevision                   [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
daemonsets                            ds              apps                           true         DaemonSet                            [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
deployments                           deploy          apps                           true         Deployment                           [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
replicasets                           rs              apps                           true         ReplicaSet                           [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
```

`kubectl api-resources -o wide | grep -i deployment`  will provide the relevant information

**apps** is the apiGroup for the deployment resource

> DaemonSet, Deployment, StatefulSet, and ReplicaSet: will no longer be served from extensions/v1beta1, apps/v1beta1, or apps/v1beta2 in v1.16.
>   Migrate to the apps/v1 API, available since v1.9. Existing persisted data can be retrieved/updated via the apps/v1 API.[/api-deprecations-in-1-16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/)

Comment: Can you expand further about how to know which of the two outputs from your above command needs to used in the `apiGroups` field.
```
k api-resources -o wide | grep -i deployment
deployments                       deploy       apps                           true         Deployment                       [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
deployments
```

Comment: I updated the answer with the example, as you can see the  header of each column.

Comment: @ColeBittel, has the answered help you to solve the issue?  If there is something missing let me know . thanks

Comment: But both `extensions` and `apps` are listed for `deployments` in the `APIGROUP`. So which one do I pick? How do I know which one to pick?

Comment: it depends on the k8s version, Extension is deprecated.  so apps is the present and future

Comment: what version of k8s are you using ?  `kubectl version --short`

Answer (score 8):

In later k8s version, `apigroup` is deprecated, and the command `kubectl api-resources -o wide` will show `apiversion` instead, which is a combination of `apigroup/version`

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky, because both groups apps and extensions are in use in recent kubernetes versions, for example
kubectl get deployments   # It is still requested  via extensions api group by default.
kubectl get deployments.apps  # request via apps group

so until deployments are removed from the extensions apigroup you have to use both apigroups in your role.

- apiGroups: ["apps","extensions"]

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67439

Answer (score 2):

It is included in the online [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-reference).

In your example, if you click through and find the documentation for [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#role-v1-rbac-authorization-k8s-io), it lists the group and version in both the sidebar ("Role v1 rbac.authorization.k8s.io") and as the first line in the actual API documentation.  Similarly, [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#deployment-v1-apps) is in group "apps" with version "v1".

In the [Role specification](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) you only put the group, and it applies to all versions.  So to control access to Deployments, you'd specify `apiGroups: [apps], resources: [deployments]`.  (This is actually [one of the examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-examples) in the RBAC documentation.)

Comment: It sounds as though you're suggesting I put `rbac.authorization.k8s.io` where the question has `<wtf goes here>`. If so, this is incorrect.

Comment: its import to get the group value from running cluster state, as there is possibility of different values

Comment: @ColeBittel Sorry, I read the question a little deeper and understand better.  I added a specific mention of the `apiGroups:` value for Deployments to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command to get apiVersion and other details.

```
 kubectl explain <Resource Name>
 kubectl explain deployment
```